# There's a way to convert static HTML to a standalone app?

Tags: html

I need to build a simple presentation in HTML and JS, but it needs to run locally as a standalone and portable app in both Windows and Mac.

There are any ways to do this?

Answer (score 2):

[Adobe Air](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/) allows you to make native apps that run on both platforms out of HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

In addition, there are already libraries out there to help you create slideshow functionality out of HTML. Erik Meyer's S5 is a popular one: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/s5/

Comment: Air applications need to be installed? I need a portable solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's the MHTML format which is supported by Internet Explorer and Opera out-of-the-box and Firefox via add-on. It let's you save a whole page including images, scripts and so on in a single file.

To create one, you could just open your web page in one of those browsers and choose "save as".

Answer (score 0):

Just save it as bunch of htmls, pictures and JSs and open in your favorite browser!

Comment: It would be so but sadly there's Internet Explorer that pop up security notifications and other boring thigs. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is way to create a simple presentation:

http://code.google.com/p/html5slides/

Example:
http://html5slides.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/template/index.html#1

Code of example:
http://code.google.com/p/html5slides/source/browse/trunk/template/index.html

To run it standalone, you need just to save it.
Or, you can use [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/).

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, but what if you take a Portable Browser? Chrome and Firefox both have a Portable App version. Another option would be to use PDF instead of HTML.